# Jetpack Compose NestedScroll bounce to opposite direction

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

[image: 1]

When I use a LazyColumn nested in Column that can scroll, sometimes I fast scroll the inner LazyColumn, the columns will bounce to the opposite direction.

Like the attached picture, when LazyColumn scroll to top, the outer Column and the inner LazyColumn will bounce to bottom.
How can I remove this effect?

Thank you in advance!

Note: the compose version is 1.2.1

code is like this:

```
@Composable
fun NestedScrollSample() {

val dataList1 = mutableListOf<Int>()

for (i in 0..6) {
    dataList1.add(i)
}

Column(
    content = {

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(Color.Blue)
                .height(360.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth()
        )


        Text(text = "List", textAlign = TextAlign.Center, modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth())
        LazyColumn(
            content = {
                itemsIndexed(dataList1) { index, item ->

                    Text(
                        text = "$index $item",
                        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .padding(vertical = 8.dp)
                    )

                    Divider(thickness = 1.dp, color = Color(0XFFE5E5E5))
                }


            }, modifier = Modifier
                .background(Color(0xFFF5F7FA))
                .height(180.dp)
                .padding(horizontal = 4.dp)
        )



        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(Color.Green)
                .height(360.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth()
        )

    }, modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .verticalScroll(state = rememberScrollState())

)

}
```

Comment: Please post some code

Comment: the code is added